# Change Password Get Request Not Changing Password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I have a MEAN application that is trying to implement a GET Request for '/changepassword'. This file is located in '/users/changepassword'. I am using Mongoose and bcryptjs for my password hashing. Please take a look at my code below.

This is /users/changepassword

```
// Change Password
router.post('/changepassword', function(req, res){
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.oldPassword;
  var newPassword = req.body.newPassword;

  User.getUserByUserName(username, function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(user === null){
      res.json({success: false, msg: "The given username does not exist."});
    }else{
      User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch)
        {
          User.changePassword(user, newPassword,function(err, changedPassword){
            if(err) throw err;
            else{
              if(changedPassword === true){
                res.json({success: true, msg: "Your password has been changed."});
              }
              else {
                res.json({success: false, msg: "Your password was unable to be changed."});
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This is the Mongoose changepassword function located in /models/user

```
module.exports.changePassword = function(user, newPassword, callback){
  var query = {username: user.username};
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash){
    if (err) throw err;
    else{
      user.password = hash;
      User.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $set: { password: user.password }}, {new: true}, function(err, newUser){
        if(err) throw err;
        else{
        bcrypt.compare(newPassword, newUser.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(isMatch);
            callback(null, isMatch);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
};
```

Here are all other functions used in the /models/user

```
module.exports.getUserByUserName = function(username, callback){
  var query = {username: username};
  User.findOne(query, callback);
};

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch){
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
};
```

When I use postman, this is the output I receive

```
{
  "success": false,
  "msg": "Your password was unable to be changed."
}
```

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was wrong!

```
module.exports.changePassword = function(user, newPassword, callback){
  var query = {username: user.username};
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){

// it has to be newPassword instead of user.password
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash){

    if (err) throw err;
    else{
      user.password = hash;
      User.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $set: { password: user.password }}, {new: true}, function(err, newUser){
        if(err) throw err;
        else{
        bcrypt.compare(newPassword, newUser.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(isMatch);
            callback(null, isMatch);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
};

// CORRECT ONE
module.exports.changePassword = function(user, newPassword, callback){
  var query = {username: user.username};
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt){
    bcrypt.hash(newPassword, salt, function(err, hash){
    if (err) throw err;
    else{
      user.password = hash;
      User.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $set: { password: user.password }}, {new: true}, function(err, newUser){
        if(err) throw err;
        else{
        bcrypt.compare(newPassword, newUser.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(isMatch);
            callback(null, isMatch);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
};
```